# How to use One to many relation using UserProfile table in MVC4 - ForeignKey Mapping in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, code-first, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I am tring to relate the "UserProfile" to another model "Data".

UserProfile Model:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

Data Model:

```
[Table("Data")]
public class Data
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int DataID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "DataName")]
    public string DataName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Created Date")]
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    public int? ManagedByUserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ManagedByUserId")]
    [Display(Name = "Managed By")]
    public UserProfile ManagedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Here ManagedByUserId is the foriegnkey in Data table.

Is there any problem with Namming convention ? However I am getting a property error `"ManagedByUser" is required`. Because of this my `ModelState` is not valid (`ModelState.IsValid` is `false`) so data is not saved.

Comment: Which direction is your relationship? Does `Data` has many `UserProfile` or is it the other way round?

Comment: `Data` has only one `UserProfile`. Its a `One to One` relation

Comment: I found a solution that, `public int? ManagedByUserId` field should not be `Nullable` and need to add `[Required]` attribute for that Field. Also need to remove `[Required]` from `public UserProfile ManagedByUser` field. If modified like this all are working. But, wht to do, if I want that `ManagedByUserId` to be `Nullable`

Comment: You can't make it Nullable, by logic you can only create Data if UserProfile exists. Also your tag said one-to-many.

Comment: What to do if, I want to make `ManagedByUserId` optional ? Suppose all the `Data` will not be having ManagedByUser.